# Eclipse RCP periodic workspace save

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am developing an RCP application in Eclipse 4.2.

I am getting an error of "Periodic workspace has encountered a problem".
My question is how to disable periodic workspace save in my RCP application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't completely disable it, but you can set the interval to be very large.

```java
IWorkspaceDescription description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getDescription();

description.setSnapshotInterval(interval in milliseconds);

ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().setDescription(description);
```

You should also investigate why you are getting problems doing the save.